# Single file upload in multiple rows of a table- formdata in react, multer with express in node - Suggestion only required

Tags: node.js, express, multer

I have a scenario like there are multiple rows in a table with two columns - one column correspond to a file and another column corresponds to a date which can be picked by user.

The only way I was able to figure out was like below - having same key for file and the date corresponding to it.
[image: Formdata representation]

But the challenge here is in my nodejs code

```
 router.post('/dosomething', upload.fields([
      { name: 'testdata1', maxCount: 1 },
      { name: 'testdata2', maxCount: 1 }
    ]), function (req, response) {
      console.log(req.files); //returns both file details
      console.log(req.body.testdata1); // returns date of testdata1
      console.log(req.body.testdata2); //returns date of testdata2
      response.json("do nothing");
})
```

The limit of how much can be uploaded isn't flexible. Consider there are 10-15 uploads possible, i would have to have 15 different keys like how i have testdata1 and testdata2, which i don't feel is a good option . Could you please suggest if there is an alternate way to achieve it ?

Answer (score 0):

One possibility is to first accept all files using `upload.any()` and then validate what was received is ok. So you'd check that the number of testdataX's in req.body equals the number of received files.

```
router.post("/dosomething", upload.any(), function (req, res) {
  // validate testdataX's in req.body match req.files.length
  // continue with processing...
});
```